# Setting a GridView's colour in WPF via code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, gridview

I've been searching for quite a long time how to do this. I don't know how to set the colour of a row item in the GridView (WPF) using *code* I don't want an example in XAML

My data comes from me loading & pulling apart an XML file. I then put it into a small class with properties and those are bound to the column to populate the data. Later, it can begin some functions on the table's data. Because this takes at some times over 10 minutes it's on a thread & I would like to colour the rows I've completed parsing depending on the result. (IE: Red for HTTP error, Orange for XML parsing error ect...)

This is the GridView's XAML:

```
<ListView Name="RepoListView" Margin="0,22,0,0">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
      <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding title}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="URL" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding url}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Subscriptions" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding dlc}" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I am then parsing the data using the url column. I am currently changing the selected item as I go through. I want to know if theres something I can do to change the specific item. Let's assume I'm on row 500:

I use: setSelected(i) which uses Dispatcher to safely change the selected row. Is there anything I can do to change the colour as well? I've been trying for hours to find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would probably go for a binding approach, code behind is ugly. Create a property with an error enum and create a DataTemplate or Style in which you bind the background to said property.

**Edit:** Example...

In your class:

```cs
public enum ParsingStatus { None, Completed, XmlError, HtmlError }

private ParsingStatus _status = ParsingStatus.None;
public ParsingStatus Status
{
    get { return _status; }
    set
    {
        if (_status != value)
        {
            _status = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can either bind to the background property using a converter like this:

```cs
public class ErrorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Employee.ParsingStatus input = (Employee.ParsingStatus)value;
        switch (input)
        {
            case Employee.ParsingStatus.None:
                return null;
            case Employee.ParsingStatus.Completed:
                return Brushes.LightGreen;
            case Employee.ParsingStatus.XmlError:
                return Brushes.Pink;
            case Employee.ParsingStatus.HtmlError:
                return Brushes.Yellow;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And the respective XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ErrorToBrushConverter x:Key="ErrorToBrushConv"/>
    ...
</Window.Resources>
    ...
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource ErrorToBrushConv}}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            ...
        </ListView>
```

Or you only specify a Style and do the switch on the status using triggers:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="XmlError">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="HtmlError">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF66"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Completed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

(*Using triggers was suggested by Robert Rossney, as you can see it is quite short and requires no code behind at all, i cannot really think of any downsides to this and i have no idea why i did not do it like this in the first place...*)

Which looks like this with the converter (the yellow of the trigger-method is more suitable):
[image: A colourful ListView]

Comment: @H.B. Thanks, Could you provide an example for me?

Comment: Appended an extensive example. Edit: Oh woops, that's a DataGrid and not a GridView, i'll try to port it...

Comment: Changed it to the ListView equivalent.

Comment: You don't need a converter; you can create a style using data triggers to set the background color based on a bound property.

Comment: @Robert Rossney I am aware of that but I don't think it makes much of a difference if you use such a simple converter which is just a switch. Probably more a matter of preference rather than performance or style.

Comment: ++ because the invested time :)

Comment: I feel like a converter with no unit tests is an accident waiting to happen (though that might just be superstition on my part).

Comment: @Robert Rossney Sorry, if that was your concern i cannot argue with you since i have no experience with organized testing, could you give an example of what might go wrong with a converter and why such problems do not occur with triggers?

Comment: What could happen with this particular converter:  you use it on a two-way binding and `ConvertBack` isn't implemented, you use it on a property whose type isn't an `Employee.ParsingStatus`.  I *think* converter errors just get swallowed up by binding, so the exceptions won't crash your app, but I'm not sure.  Triggers may fail to fire, but that's the worst that they'll ever fail.